# If Yes button of Dialog box is clicked, run program again

Tags: c#

I'm writing a grade calculator, and at the end,  I ask the user if they have another grade to calculate.

```
 Console.Write("Do you have another grade to calculate? ");
        moreGradesToCalculate = Console.ReadLine();
        moreGradesToCalculate = moreGradesToCalculate.ToUpper();
```

I want to display a dialog box with the options of Yes or No.

I want to be able to run the program again, if the DialogResult is Yes, and do something else if the result is No.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `do...while(...)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `do/while` construct like

```
do {
     Console.Write("Do you have another grade to calculate Y/N? "); 
     var moreGradesToCalculate = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
     if(moreGradesToCalculate == "Y")
        //do something  
     else if(moreGradesToCalculate == "N")
         break;

}while(true);
```

Comment: while(1) in C#? And I personally don't like this coding style, why writing a while(true) when a while(moreGradesToCalculate == "Y") is more than enough?

Comment: @BlackBear: in your case you need to declare `moreGradesToCalculate` **outside** of `while` loop, in my case I can avoid declaring the state variable outside of it. There is no looser or winner in *this* case, just a matter of coding style.

Comment: @Tigran with all due respect you aren't declaring `moreGradesToCalculate` inside the loop either.  You missing a `var` or `string` or some other type in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to run the whole program again, just start over getting numbers for calculating the grades (wrap your code in a loop).

For the DialogBox, simply import `System.Window.Forms` assembly and use this:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to start over?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (result == DialogResult.No) {
    // TODO: Exit the program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dialog box, you'll have to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and also add a `using` statement for the same namespace at the top of your file. Then you just have to check the result of calling the `Show` method on the `MessageBox` object at the end of a Do-While loop. For example:

```
do
{
    // Grading calculation work...

}
while (MessageBox.Show("Do you have another grade to calculate?",
    "Continue Grading?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes);
```

This will keep looping until the user clicks No.

If you don't want to keep using the mouse, do it all on the command line with this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
do
{
    // Grading work...

    Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to input more grades? (Y/N)");
    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey();
    }
    while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Y && key.Key != ConsoleKey.N);
}
while (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
```

Here's a link to the reference material on looping - or 'Iteration Statements' from Microsoft. The `Do-While` is one of a few you should try to learn off by heart when you're just starting out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx